# Accessing key of nested JSON object where key is dynamic

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm using the below to log a JSON key which is dynamic to the console; however, the object which the key belongs to has another object nested inside it which I need to access a value of. A further complication is that this objects key contains special characters so I have to use square brackets. How would this be possible?

```
for (var key in data.query.results.json) {
    console.log(key);
}
```

I've tried doing: `console.log(key["http:__purl.org_rss_1.0_title"].value);` and some other variations but nothing seems to be working.

Comment: it isn't `key['some string']`, it is `data.query.results.json[key]`.

Comment: No that doesn't work. That only returns 'Value: [object Object]'. I need to log a value of that object,

Comment: [object Object] means you're trying to convert an object to a string.  Are you alerting it or something?

Comment: Ultimately I need to append the value of that object to html but for the moment I just want to be able to log it to the console, or alert it.

Comment: Well, you can't alert an object or log the value to HTML without stringifying it (which is likely what you'll wind up doing).   What console are you using that isn't showing you an object inspection?

Comment: `for (var key in data.query.results.json){console.log(data.query.results.json[key]);}` should be all you need to do in most circumstances.

Comment: Most perhaps but not in this particular circumstance.

Comment: It is possible that something else in the chain has broken, and the string is actually equivalent to 'object Object'.  Can I assume this is Ajax?  Have you checked the network inspection to see what is coming over the wire?  You know you can also `console.log(data.query.results.json)`, too, right?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, just do to "for" statements one in another if the object contains other objects (2 levels)

```js
for (var key in data.query.results.json) {

  for (var key2 in data.query.results.json[key]) {
    if(key2 == "whateverKey")
      console.log(data.query.results.json[key][key2]);
  }

}
```

If there are further levels of nesting, use a recursive function.

Comment: This gives me all the objects at the next level down and their values but I only want to log the object with the key "http:__purl.org_rss_1.0_title" - how would I modify it to do that?

Comment: a simple "if" in front of the console.log

Comment: That doesn't return anything.

Comment: Haha. I did change it yeah, it seems to be doing something now but not quite what I was expecting - I'm getting a list of about 100 objects. I don't think this code is accessing the value of the "http:__purl.org_rss_1.0_title" object, as it should just return a list of book titles.

Comment: Actually it is working, it gives me a list of objects and the 'type' and 'value', with value being my book titles, but how do I log just the value and not the object itself?

Comment: add another ".value" at the end

Comment: A further quick question: the If statement works but what if there are multiple objects which satisfy that condition? How would I only log the value of say the first one?